# Delphi 10.4 - DataSnap - Parallel calls - [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite]-326. Cannot perform the action, because the previous action is in progress

Tags: delphi, firedac, datasnap

I'm writing a DataSnap application and I am receiving the following error message below when calling a method in parallel (calling the same method on client A and client B).

"[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite]-326. Cannot perform the action, because the previous action is in progress."

The DataSnap Server was created with Delphi's own "Wizard", it has a DataModule that contains an FDQuery connected to an FdConnection.

The query is a simple "select" on a table and is configured as "amBlocking" in "Resource Options".

The database used is SQLite.

In the "WebModule" the "DsServerClass" is configured as "Session".

When I call the method through client A, several times it works fine, without problems. However, if called by client A and client B at the same time the error occurs.

If the DsServerClass is already configured as "Session", shouldn't it isolate the method, the connection and the query for each client?

I also changed the "DsServerClass" to "invocation" and the problem continues.

Comment: Add a log in the `OnCreate` event of the DataModule and you will find out if it is created several times or just once.

Comment: Are the FDQuery and FDConnection components created at design-time? In that case clientA and clientB share database connection. It is better to create query and connection component at run-time.

Comment: Ok @Erwin I changed the creations of FDQuerys and FDConnections to be created at runtime and that solved the problem, thanks for the tip.